# full disk encryption with separate /home partition

Tags: system-installation, encryption

I would like to install ubuntu 22.04 with full disk encryption, but having /home on a separate LVM partition, instead of having /home and / on the same partition.

Debian has been providing this for a while, so it should be possible, right? Maybe I missed something, but the installer, after selecting "full disk encryption" seems to create one LVM volume which is formated in ext4 and used for both /home and /.

I have been trying for 3 hrs now, and really I cannot find how to do it, so I definitely need some help. Thx for any tip!

Comment: You haven't said what Ubuntu 22.04 product you're trying to use, Ubuntu 22.04 LTS ISOs are available using `ubiquity` installer, `subiquity` with two *flavors* of 22.04 using `calamares`.. but you didn't specify which product thus what installer you actually tried (*or are asking about*).

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that you cannot do full disk encryption with partitions using the Ubuntu desktop installer. However, you can achieve what you want, but it does take a bit more time.

I've done what you want to do on my Lenovo Thinkbook T15 Gen2 to install Ubuntu 22.04 (and upgraded just recently to 23.04): separate boot, system, swap, and home partitions using LUKS encryption.

What you'll end up doing is first running the Ubuntu installer, but only to a point, and then dropping into command line to prepare your disk(s). Then finally, you can again run the installer and complete the Ubuntu installation.

The resources that I've used are (all external):

- https://stephencox.net/blog/install-ubuntu-full-disk-encryption-home-partition/
- https://gist.github.com/superjamie/d56d8bc3c9261ad603194726e3fef50f
- https://github.com/nbros652/LUKS-guided-manual-partitioning

I'd recommend that you review the first two sites to get a general understanding of the procedure (they're both very similar). The third site is a Github script that will do much of this prep work for you. It's been a couple of years since I used this script, but again, very helpful to understand the overall process.